# how to see ready HTML after xsl-transformation in a browser?

Tags: browser, xslt

I have xml with header *xml-stylesheet* that indicates to xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="1.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
......
</root>
```

In a browser this will transform to html. How to see ready HTML after xsl-transformation in the browser? If I choose *View Source* I see XML of course. I'm interested in Firefox and Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DOM inspector instead of source viewer.

Comment: You can use firebufg for firefox or try F12 for IE.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the FireBug plugin in Firefox, this shows you the currently active DOM, which is your generated HTML.

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843/

Comment: There is an addon called "DebugBar" for IE, you could try that one.